# Showing an integral/kernel function is measurable.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

We have two measurable spaces $(X,A)$ and $(Y, B)$, and a kernel $K(x,y)$. Also, $f$ is some $B$- measurable function. We wish to show that $x \to \int f(y)K(x,y)$ is $A$-measurable.

My thought process:

Call the function in question $g(x)$. For our function to be $A$-measurable, we need that for any $b \in B$

$g^{-1}(b) \in A$.

Now, we assumed $f$ is $B$-measurable and we know that by definition, for each $x \in X$,

$b \to K(x,b)$ is a measure on $(Y,B)$.

So the integral is well defined (with $K$ being like a very general version of "dx" in a sense, I think...)

Though, none of this gives me a clue on how to tie it to $A$-measurability.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do we get to assume $K$ is measurable?

Comment: @BernardW Oh, yes we do!

Comment: Consider the more general problem. For a measurable function $f(x,y)$ is the map $x \mapsto \int f(x,y)\,dy$ measurable? Proving that this is the case is an important step in the proof of Fubini's theorem, but note that this only holds for $\sigma$ countable measure spaces. Can't remember the details so I'll leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it in the usual way of approximating by simple functions.

First let $f = f^+ - f^-$, so we only need to consider positive functions. Let $f_n^+ = \sum_m a_n^m \chi_{B_n^m}$ be an increasing sequence of simple functions converging to $f^+$. Then, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem,
\begin{align}
Kf^+(x) :=\int K(x, dy)f^+(y) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int K(x, dy)f_n^+(y)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_mK(x, B_n^m)a_n^m.
\end{align}
Since $K(x, dy)$ is a kernel, $K(x, B_n^m)$ is measurable, so $Kf^+(x)$ being the limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable. The same goes for $f^-$ and thus $Kf = Kf^+ - Kf^-$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a write-up written by me. See if it helps. It basically uses the Fubini Theorem.

[image]